# Issues with Rigging Weight paints error?

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I'm having serious issues at the moment with rigging and modelling a droid I've built. essentially the problem is as follows: 
I weight paint the hip area, all is good. during me Weights test I find that some of those weights are in fact attached to another bone. I remove it and carry on applying the weight to the right armature bone. then, when I return to the incorrect bone, I find that the weighting has been reapplied. I had a similar problem on the hands and don't know what the source is. any advice?

[image]
this is a picture of the wrong bone, note the highlighted crotch
[image]

this image demonstrates the highlighting on the correct bone

Comment: How are you removing the weight ? Are there modifiers ? Have you applied scale?

Comment: @Patdog I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I have no active modifiers but when I made the mesh it was separate then modified to look right and joined up. and I'm just subtracting in the weight paint menu

Comment: @Cyanidewaffles could you please share your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: Also suggest you upload your file here blend -exchange.giantcowfilms.com - I think you might be painting weights through your mesh. Easiest way to check this in by looking at the vertex groups in edit mode. The vertex groups should have the same name as the bone. Select the group for the bone in question and see what vertices light up when you click select in the vertex group...

Comment: @Patdog I cannot seem to find the website you have suggested. concurning vertex groups, I'm not entirely sure about their function or true meaning. I am not yet familiar with all tools and terminology

Comment: This should also work http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - upload your file there and paste the link back in your topic. Add a comment when done and I'll gladly have a look. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/ if you are having trouble uploading...